# Использование собственной карты (прозрачный png файл) над картой Яндекса

Tags: yandex-maps-api, yandex-maps-jsapi

Я пробую интегрировать мой прозрачный PNG файл, который является более подробной картой той местности, которая меня интересует, но при добавлении этого самого верхнего слоя, при каждом зумировании (увличении или уменьшении масштабов карты) происходит то, что размер этого самого файла, который над картой, не меняется. Хотя по идее он должен автоматом зуммироваться вместе с основной картой.

4 часа усиленных поисков по документации к сожалению не принесли сколько либо ощутимых результатов.

Вы можете подсказать источник, где можно найти пример того как интегрировать свои кастом карты поверх яндексовских карт?

С этой проблемой я столкнулся в Google Maps, но смог ее успешно решить. Вот [тут](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/maptype-image-overlay?authuser=0) информация о том, что именно я хочу сделать в ядексовских картах.

А вот какого результата хочу добиться:

[image: google maps]

Буду крайне признателен получить помощь от сообщества

Answer (score 1):

В песочнице есть вот такой пример: https://tech.yandex.ru/maps/jsbox/2.1/custom_map

```js
ymaps.ready(function () {

    var LAYER_NAME = 'user#layer',
        MAP_TYPE_NAME = 'user#customMap',
    // Директория с тайлами.
        TILES_PATH = 'https://sandbox.api.maps.yandex.net/examples/ru/2.1/custom_map/images/tiles',
    /* Для того чтобы вычислить координаты левого нижнего и правого верхнего углов прямоугольной координатной
     * области, нам необходимо знать максимальный зум, ширину и высоту изображения в пикселях на максимальном зуме.
     */
        MAX_ZOOM = 4,
        PIC_WIDTH = 2526,
        PIC_HEIGHT = 1642;

    /**
     * Конструктор, создающий собственный слой.
     */
    var Layer = function () {
        var layer = new ymaps.Layer(TILES_PATH + '/%z/tile-%x-%y.jpg', {
            // Если есть необходимость показать собственное изображение в местах неподгрузившихся тайлов,
            // раскомментируйте эту строчку и укажите ссылку на изображение.
            // notFoundTile: 'url'
        });
        // Указываем доступный диапазон масштабов для данного слоя.
        layer.getZoomRange = function () {
            return ymaps.vow.resolve([0, 4]);
        };
        // Добавляем свои копирайты.
        layer.getCopyrights = function () {
            return ymaps.vow.resolve('©');
        };
        return layer;
    };
    // Добавляем в хранилище слоев свой конструктор.
    ymaps.layer.storage.add(LAYER_NAME, Layer);

    /**
     * Создадим новый тип карты.
     * MAP_TYPE_NAME - имя нового типа.
     * LAYER_NAME - ключ в хранилище слоев или функция конструктор.
     */
    var mapType = new ymaps.MapType(MAP_TYPE_NAME, [LAYER_NAME]);
    // Сохраняем тип в хранилище типов.
    ymaps.mapType.storage.add(MAP_TYPE_NAME, mapType);

    // Вычисляем размер всех тайлов на максимальном зуме.
    var worldSize = Math.pow(2, MAX_ZOOM) * 256,
        /**
         * Создаем карту, указав свой новый тип карты.
         */
        map = new ymaps.Map('map', {
            center: [0, 0],
            zoom: 2,
            controls: ['zoomControl'],
            type: MAP_TYPE_NAME
        }, {

            // Задаем в качестве проекции Декартову. При данном расчёте центр изображения будет лежать в координатах [0, 0].
            projection: new ymaps.projection.Cartesian([[PIC_HEIGHT / 2 - worldSize, -PIC_WIDTH / 2], [PIC_HEIGHT / 2, worldSize - PIC_WIDTH / 2]], [false, false]),
            // Устанавливаем область просмотра карты так, чтобы пользователь не смог выйти за пределы изображения.
            restrictMapArea: [[-PIC_HEIGHT / 2, -PIC_WIDTH / 2], [PIC_HEIGHT / 2, PIC_WIDTH / 2]]

            // При данном расчёте, в координатах [0, 0] будет находиться левый нижний угол изображения,
            // правый верхний будет находиться в координатах [PIC_HEIGHT, PIC_WIDTH].
            // projection: new ymaps.projection.Cartesian([[PIC_HEIGHT - worldSize, 0], [PIC_HEIGHT, worldSize]], [false, false]),
            // restrictMapArea: [[0, 0], [PIC_HEIGHT, PIC_WIDTH]]
        });

    // Ставим метку в центр координат. Обратите внимание, координаты метки задаются в порядке [y, x].
    var point = new ymaps.Placemark([0, 0], {
        balloonContent: 'Координаты метки: [0, 0]'
    }, {
        preset: 'islands#darkOrangeDotIcon'
    });

    map.geoObjects.add(point);
});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="ru">
<head>
    <title>Создание собственной карты</title>
    <meta charset="utf-8">

    <style>
        html, body, .map {
            width: 100%;
            height: 100%;
            margin: 0;
            padding: 0;
        }
    </style>
    <!--
        Укажите свой API-ключ. Тестовый ключ НЕ БУДЕТ работать на других сайтах.
        Получить ключ можно в Кабинете разработчика: https://developer.tech.yandex.ru/keys/
    -->
    <script src="https://api-maps.yandex.ru/2.1/?apikey=7565de29-a5c8-4d64-abb5-20c85252705e&lang=ru_RU"></script>
    <script src="custom_map.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="map" class="map"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: День добрый. Хорошо бы основное из статьи по ссылке добавить в ответ ^_^

Comment: Красивый пример. А можно его перенести в ответ, а не просто дать ссылку?

Comment: Да, конечно, добавил пример в ответ ^^'